# Hive server not coming up

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hive-metastore

Hive server is not coming up with following error. I cannot re-initialize hive-metastore because i do not want to lose data which is already there in cluster. Cluster settings are fine because we have been using the same cluster for more than a year without this issue. Thanks in advance!

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:141)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:545)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1627)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3590)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1625)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOUserException: The query returned more than one instance BUT either unique is set to true or only aggregates are to be returned, so should have returned one result maximum
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.store.query.QueryNotUniqueException: The query returned more than one instance BUT either unique is set to true or only aggregates are to be returned, so should have returned one result maximum
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:636)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:388)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.execute(JDOQuery.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getMRole(ObjectStore.java:4091)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.addRole(ObjectStore.java:3731)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.addRole(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles_core(HiveMetaStore.java:644)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultRoles(HiveMetaStore.java:636)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.datanucleus.store.query.QueryNotUniqueException: The query returned more than one instance BUT either unique is set to true or only aggregates are to be returned, so should have returned one result maximum
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1879)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithArray(Query.java:1733)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:365)
    ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue with our hive metastore. One table called ROLES had a duplicate for the admin role, thus creating the problem.

I deleted one of the roles manually and it started working.

```
mysql> select * from metastore.ROLES;
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| ROLE_ID | CREATE_TIME | OWNER_NAME | ROLE_NAME |
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|       1 |  1582027792 | admin      | admin     |
|       2 |  1582027792 | public     | public    |
|       3 |  1582027792 | admin      | admin     |
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+

mysql> delete from metastore.ROLES where ROLE_ID=3;
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| ROLE_ID | CREATE_TIME | OWNER_NAME | ROLE_NAME |
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|       1 |  1582027792 | admin      | admin     |
|       2 |  1582027792 | public     | public    |
+---------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```